# django served file returned empty on windows, not on mac

Tags: django, file, response

```
def _tarFiles(filepaths):
print "create tar file from all files in file list and save to temp working dir. returns tarfile path "
try:
    savePathDir = settings.TAR_FILE_TARGET_DIRECTORY
    if not os.path.exists(savePathDir):
        os.makedirs(savePathDir)

    tarredfiles = tarfile.open(settings.TAR_FILE_TARGET_DIRECTORY + '/' + 'responsefiles.tar',mode='w')
    for f in filepaths:
        tarredfiles.add(f)

    tarredfiles.close()
    return ("Ok", settings.TAR_FILE_TARGET_DIRECTORY + '/' + 'responsefiles.tar')

except Exception as e:
    return ("Error in "+ inspect.stack()[0][3] + " " + e.message, None)

 def sendFiles(files):
    try:
        result, tarfilename = _tarFiles(files)
        if result == 'Ok':
            try:
                print tarfilename
                wrapper = FileWrapper(file(tarfilename))
                response = HttpResponse(wrapper, content_type='application/x-tar') #zip,avi,png,jpeg, etc...
                response['Content-Disposition'] = 'attachment; filename=' + tarfilename#tarredfiles.name #eg. myfile.zip
                response['Content-Length'] = str(os.path.getsize(tarfilename))
                return ("Ok",response)
            except Exception as e:
                return ("Error in "+ inspect.stack()[0][3] + " " + e.message, None)

        else:
            return (result,None)

    except Exception as e:
        return ("Error in "+ inspect.stack()[0][3] + " " +e.message,None)
```

tarfilename is the complete path to the file.
The content-length looks right (comparing actual file to getsize).

Works on a mac running runserver. Returns a partial file on windows running runserver. Or completely empty file if I step through on windows.

The target directory and filename generated is "tarred_files/responsefiles.tar"
the file size is 90K and the os.path.getsize returned is 92160

What am I doing that would cause an empty file to be downloaded?

Comment: "What am I doing that would cause an empty file to be downloaded?" Returning None if the result of _tarFiles is not "Ok". I'd bet that _tarFiles is failing on Windows. Can you paste the code for that function?

Comment: sure, but I walked through in debug and it was getting through... I will check again!

Comment: Yes it returns the response with the content headers populated (properly?)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For windows, you need to add "rb" to file.

like so:

```
wrapper = FileWrapper(file(tarfilename,'rb'))
```

Also, Content-Length should use a integer, not a string

like so:

```
response['Content-Length'] = os.path.getsize(tarfilename)
```